# How to build spine for 3d model

Tags: 3d, geometry, edges, topology, spine

I have a set of 3d shapes with 2 or 3 borders like it's shown bellow.
There is no problem to find and build edge paths (highlighted green), but I need also to find arbitrary paths (magenta spines) connecting these borders.

[image]
[image]

Is there any algorithm to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem could be divided into several steps:

[image]

a) finding the closest vertex b on the opposite border by comparing
   distance from given vertex a to all opposite vertices.
b) collecting closest faces
c) using Dijkstra's or any other pathfinding algorithm to build path
   from face (polygon) sides.

By now, I don't know how to do step b) efficiently